# Make elements in ImageView array visible using Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview

I have an array of `ImageView` with a number of invisible elements that I would like to make visible sequentially (i.e. make the first one visible, wait for half a second, make the next one visible, and so on) using either `Thread` or `runOnUiThread`.

I have tried the following:

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
th.start();
```

and

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            im5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

But I don't get the desired effect. What happens is that all images are made visible at the same time instead of one after the other.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sleeping your UI thread is always bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. This is how I managed to do it:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},500);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                im3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},1000);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                im4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},1500);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                im4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},2000);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter=1; //Global variable

private void visibleImageview()
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(counter==1)
                {
                     im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if(counter==2)
                {
                    im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if(counter==3)
                {
                    im3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


                ++counter;
                if(couter<=3)
                visibleImageview();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```